# Android Maps to find nearby pharmacy

Tags: android

I have created the below code to find the nearby pharmacies.I would like to know if any changes are required in my code.It's throwing some errors.

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;


public class MapActivity {
    Intent mapintent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=Pharmacy&hl=en"));
     startActivity(mapintent);

    }
```

Comment: What errors is it throwing? Where is your `onCreate` method?

Comment: and what is the error? please post your logcat too.

Comment: It is asking me to create method body..Should  i giv tat inside oncreate method?

Comment: yes..you'll have to extend Activity and do the above code in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

Google just released the Places API in the latest Play Services: read about it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html).

You can of course use that in conjunction with the Location services, but the idea of parsing the results of a maps query doesn't make a lot of sense any more.